# Download nupkg from NuGet Feed into the working folder of second TC server

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

We have 2 TC instances (local TC and second TC), in a local instance we have only a Build step, and that is generating a .nupkg.
From this local TC NuGet feed we want to take that packet and use it into second TC server, and from here to publish and deploy to Octopus.

We are encountering some difficulties in using the .nupkg generated, and use that into the second Team City server, because the nuget pack is not downloaded into the working folder of the second TC server, it's only in the NuGet feed.

We get this error on the second TC server: Failed to find files to create packages matching: [ *.nupkg] under C:\BuildAgent\work\36db94a2ba9df36a.

Basically we need that .nupkg downloaded from NuGet feed into the working folder of second TC instance, in order to be able to deploy it in Octopus.

How can we accomplish this?

We tried with NuGet Installer runner type, but seems like not a good solution for us, because we don't have a .sln at this point, only after the pack is being used we create the .sln.

Do we have other options?
Thanks

Comment: You forgot the error message in your post. Do you have a build configuration with a .Net solution on the second server that tries to uses the nuget feed from the local one?

Comment: Thanks for this, error message attached. No we do not have a .Net solution that we can use at this step. We have a nuget packet already published on an external nuget feed, and we want to take it from that feed and deploy it with Octopus.

Comment: So why do you need the second TC server? You should use the Nuget feed (url like https://domain.invalid/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/), its credentials and then you can use the packages....

Comment: We need one local TC server because there are some special requirements for an application, and another one for the company. This is the reason why it's a bit complicated to do these connections between them.  So you are saying to use the feed directly, but I guess you are thinking to use it with NuGet Installer runner right?  This is what we started with, but we did not had any VS .sln for this step at this time. The VS solution is mandatory for NuGet installer step.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install in-house nuget server (for example [ProGet](https://inedo.com/proget), or [create yours](http://nugetserver.net/))
2. Push nuget packages from first TC to nuget server
3. Download nuget packages from feed to second TC, or anywhere you like.
4. You can use this feed in Octopus as package source

Hope this helps.